# ng-model inside ng-repeat doesn't work and I can't update all values of ng-repeat

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

In the code, there's `ng-repeat`, and I have to update `frais` of all values displayed by `ng-repeat`. I can't update the `frais` because it's inside `ng-repeat` , when I put it outside it works, but I have to put it inside to update every value of ng-repeat.

#### file.html

```
<ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="FactureAdminCtrl">

<ion-list ng-repeat = "selectedName in selected">
      <div class="item item-divider center-text" 
           name="codeE" ng-model="selectedName.CodeEnvoiColis"> 
        {{selectedName.CodeEnvoiColis}}
      </div>  

      <label class="item item-input">
      <input width="20%" type="text" 
          placeholder="Frais" ng-model="selectedName.FraisFact" 
          style="color:#BA1B1B;">
      </div> 
      </label>

</ion-list>  

    <a class="button button-info" href="#/factureAdmin" `
          ng-click=updateFact(selectedName)> Submit </a>
```

#### app.js

```
$scope.updateFact = function(selectedName){ 

   $http.post(  
        "http://localhost/deb/updatFact.php",  
        { 

        'FraisFact':$scope.selectedName.FraisFact,
        'CodeEnvoiColis':$scope.selectedName.CodeEnvoiColis,
      }
   ).success(function(data){  
        alert(data);                                
   });  

}
```

How can I do please!

Comment: Is your submit anchor inside ng-repeat ionl-ist ?

Comment: No it's outside

Comment: Then how know which list/row is going to be update ?

Comment: When I put it inside, it generates many button submit of every ng-repeat value, but me I have to update all values of ng-repeat with one button submit

Comment: The first `ng-model` is on a `<div>` tag. That won't work. The `ng-model` directive works only on `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` tags. For more information, see [AngularJS ng-model Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel).

Comment: Thank you for this information! Do you have another proposal please!

Comment: Eliminate any issues that aren't relevant to the problem. Mismatched closing `</div>` tags and `ng-model` directives on non-input elements distract from the issue. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

**Provide index to ng-model inside ng-repeat**

```
<ion-list ng-repeat = "(key,value) in selected" {{selectedName[key]=value;""}}>
          <div class="item item-divider center-text" name="codeE" ng-model="selectedName[key].CodeEnvoiColis"> {{selectedName[key].CodeEnvoiColis}} </div>  

          <label class="item item-input">
          <input width="20%" type="text" placeholder="Frais" ng-model="selectedName[key].FraisFact" style="color:#BA1B1B;"></div> 
          </label>
</ion-list>  

    <a class="button button-info" href="#/factureAdmin" ng-click=updateFact(selectedName[key])> Submit </a>
```

app.js

```
$scope.selectedName = []; //defined empty

$scope.updateFact = function(selectedName){ 

           $http.post(  
                "http://localhost/deb/updatFact.php",  
                { 

                'FraisFact':selectedName.FraisFact,
                'CodeEnvoiColis':selectedName.CodeEnvoiColis,
              }
           ).success(function(data){  
                alert(data);                                
           });  
    }
```

**app.js 2nd version : When updating all values**

```
<a class="button button-info" href="#/factureAdmin" ng-click=updateFact()> Submit </a>
```

app.js

```
$scope.selectedName = []; //defined empty

$scope.updateFact = function(){ 

            console.log("check if values updating ", $scope.selectedName)

           $http.post(  
                "http://localhost/deb/updatFact.php",  
                { 

                data: $scope.selectedName   //put logic on backend to update all data
              }
           ).success(function(data){  
                alert(data);                                
           });  
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I did what you suggested , but This generates this error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'FraisFact' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.insertFact

Comment: check updated app.js code and you need find the index of row/list going to be update

Comment: how! can you explain please !

Comment: Thank you, I check it, but it gets me an error because "FraisFact" and "CodeEnvoiColis" are not definded in app.js !!

Comment: Because in the .php file , I call this two values :       
      $CodeEnvoiColis = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->CodeEnvoiColis);  

      $FraisFact = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->FraisFact);       
      

    $query = "UPDATE colis 
    SET 
    FraisFact='$FraisFact'
    WHERE CodeEnvoiColis='$CodeEnvoiColis'";